# dismiss card for certain period of time

Tags: design-patterns

I've been tasked to apply a dismiss interaction to some UI cards that act as cross selling ads. We don't want to allow the user to dismiss them forever, just for a period of 30 days before they re-appear again.

Our design system is loosely based on Material Design, but I am struggling to find an existing pattern that would suit this behaviour and can't recall seeing anything in other products.

I've come up with the following ideas, but not sure if they feel right. Solution needs to work on desktop and mobile devices. Are there any existing patterns out there for cards?

[image: dismiss cards]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be sure but it looks like the user doesn't have any option other than closing it for 30 days.

***If your only option in the "Close" button is to "Hide for 30 days", why make it a two-step process?***

Simply inform the user that the ad would be hidden for 30 days once they hit the close button. You can use the card itself to display that info by replacing the ad with a text on the lines of "The ad would be hidden for 30 days"

---

<sub>As an aside, this is considered as a dark pattern in the UX world and research has shown that it deters users from the application if they encounter it on a regular basis. I'd suggest having an ad preferences option where the user has the control over ads being shown or have a "pay to remove ads" model.</sub>

Comment: Yeah I agree it feels like a dark pattern, so I will question why we need to it function this way. I like your idea of reducing to a one step process, I think this might be the best option if it can't be dismissed forever.